# SyntaxError: Unexpected Number (JSON.parse)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

My JSON string,

```
JSON.parse('{"start_date_time": ["2012-12-05 04:45:42.135000", "None"], "terminal_no": ["T1081", "None"], "master_doc_no": ["100008", "100008"], "notes": ["", ""], "doc_no": ["1000018", "1000019"], "location_code": ["1005", "1005"], "end_date_time": ["2012-12-05 05:27:04.529000", "None"], "doc_status": ["CC Ended", "Draft"], "bc_list": ["[{\"465\":\"85\"},{\"306\":\"6\"},{\"306\":\"47\"},{\"306\":\"366\"},{\"306\":\"634\"}]", "[{\"257\":\"14\"}]"]}')
```

But its throwing **SyntaxError: Unexpected Number**

Where am i wrong over here?

Comment: Validates just fine using JSONLint: http://jsonlint.com/ Is there any more information about the error?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, The error definitely occurs.  Throw it in your browser console.  It has to do with `bc_list` data.

Answer (score 5):

You can start by simplifying this down to where the problem occurs, in `bc_list`...

```
JSON.parse('{"bc_list": ["", "{\"257\":\"14\"}]"]}')
```

The issue is that your backslashes are being considered for the outer quotes on `JSON.parse()` instead of the inner data.  You must escape the backslashes as well.

```
JSON.parse('{"bc_list": ["", "{\\"257\\":\\"14\\"}]"]}')
```

Your whole line fixed becomes:

```
JSON.parse('{"start_date_time": ["2012-12-05 04:45:42.135000", "None"], "terminal_no": ["T1081", "None"], "master_doc_no": ["100008", "100008"], "notes": ["", ""], "doc_no": ["1000018", "1000019"], "location_code": ["1005", "1005"], "end_date_time": ["2012-12-05 05:27:04.529000", "None"], "doc_status": ["CC Ended", "Draft"], "bc_list": ["[{\\"465\\":\\"85\\"},{\\"306\\":\\"6\\"},{\\"306\\":\\"47\\"},{\\"306\\":\\"366\\"},{\\"306\\":\\"634\\"}]", "[{\\"257\\":\\"14\\"}]"]}')
```

Don't use JSON data within strings within JSON data.  It's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

This normally means your you are missing an operator, or have an illegal operator, in a calculation.

For example:

```
var a = 1000 * 1000; // correct
var b = 1000 1000;   // incorrect
var c = 1234;        // correct
var d = 1,234;       // incorrect
```

vars b and d will result in:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```